In p-aminophenol, why does adding tosylate to the amino group make the phenol more acidic?
In Workbook for organic synthesis: the disconnection approach, Chapter 5 Q1, it states that pyridine is not strong enough to remove the phenolic proton in p-aminophenol (molecule 4), but is strong enough to remove the phenolic proton when a tosylate is substituted onto the amino group (molecule 6).

Why does substituting a tosylate onto the amino group make the phenol more acidic?

Why wouldn't it? While it acts mostly on amino group, pKa of OH is also lowered a bit.

If you used a very strong base, you could even get a dianion from this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloramine-T

The tosylate group has the following structure

Note that the tosyl group is attached to the parent compound through the sulphur.
When the tosylate group is substituted in the amino group of p-aminophenol, it reduces the +M effect of the amino group, because of its resonance with the nitrogen lone pair (see figure)
The newly formed positive charge on nitrogen acts as a strong withdrawing force, and thus stabilizes the phenoxide ion.
The extra stability of the phenoxide ion because of the tosyl group is the reason why the acidity of the phenolic hydrogen increases when the amino group is tosylated.

Another Explanation
It is well known that a group's +M nature tends to reduce the acidity of the compound. By tosylating the amino group, we are technically reducing its +M nature, and thus increasing the compound's acidity.
